# Rails: Dates without Hyphens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to accept date `params` without hyphens, such as `20110929`.  In Rails/Ruby, how can I convert this to a `DateTime` object?  Do I need to edit the string manually, adding the appropriate hyphens, or is there some magic I'm not aware of?

Thanks guys!

**EDIT:**

Answered my own question, but unfortunately I can't accept it yet (low reputation):

```
DateTime.parse('20110929')
```

**EDIT 2:**

As pointed out below, my above "answer" is probably not the best.  See accepted answer below.

Comment: Beware, plain `.parse` will try to "guess" the format, and might occasionally guess it incorrectly.

Comment: So write your answer as a separate answer, and accept that one 24 hours later. You cannot accept your own answer immediately.

Comment: @Romain If that's the case, then your answer is likely the better option.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9.2 you can use `#strptime`. In some cases, if the date format to parse is common, `#parse` should work as well.

```
require 'date'
require 'time'

DateTime.strptime("20110929", "%Y%m%d")
# => #<DateTime: 2011-09-29T00:00:00+00:00 (4911667/2,0/1,2299161)>
```

Comment: Thanks.  You win by about a minute :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `Date.strptime(params[:the_date], '%y%m%d')`. See the [apidock](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strptime/class).